# permission denied on running script despite +x

Tags: bash, shell-script, permissions

Script is on exec partition (under /home/~~~ ) and have +x flag (-rwxr-xr-x ).

executable on bash shell (not with script) but not on script.
script is quite simple.

```
#!/bin/bash

data=cat $PWD/.git/config | awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)if($i~"merge")print$(i+2)}'
echo data : $data
```

result :

```
/home001/myaccount/uploader.sh: line 3: /home001/myaccount/mydirectory/.git/config: Permission denied
```

target file's permission is symbolic and 777 like below.

```
lrwxrwxrwx
```

But executable and working well at bash command line.

```
myaccount@myserver:~/mydirectory$ cat $PWD/.git/config|awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)if($i~"merge")print$(i+2)}'
mybranch
```

Script has +x flag and on executable partition. 
Also executable without script but not on script. 
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
data=cat $PWD/.git/config
```

This temporarily sets the shell variable `data` to have the value `cat` and then attempts to execute the file `$PWD/.git/config`.   That is unfortunate because you probably didn't want to execute it.

You likely intended:

```
data=$(cat $PWD/.git/config | awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)if($i~"merge")print$(i+2)}')
```

The above will run your `cat` command, sending its output to `awk` and saving awk's output in the variable `data`.  If this is what you wanted, then the `cat` is superfluous.  Replace the above with:

```
data=$(awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)if($i~"merge")print$(i+2)}' $PWD/.git/config)
```

#### Interpreting the error message

```
/home001/myaccount/uploader.sh: line 3: /home001/myaccount/mydirectory/.git/config: Permission denied
```

From the above, we know that `uploader.sh` was executing.  This means that there was no problem with the permissions of `uploader.sh`.  The error occurs on line 3 of `uploader.sh` which is the command:

```
data=cat $PWD/.git/config | awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)if($i~"merge")print$(i+2)}'
```

The `Permission denied` error occurred while the shell was attempting to execute this line.

Comment: It works with your replace. I already know from the error msg, problem is on my command at script. But with same command, without script, it works. Is there any difference with/without script running?

Comment: Generally, if something works without a script, it should also work in a script.  Exceptions to this occur when aliases or other interactive features are used: they work on the command line but (by default, anyway) aren't recognized inside scripts.